# How to access/use Indy server/client 's OnReceive and OnSend event ?

Tags: c++builder, indy

I use c++ builder XE8, and I am a beginner. I want to use `OnReceive` and `OnSend` event of `Indy server and client` to make it work in `non-blocking` mode. I have read that Indy server/client works in blocking mode, and to make it work i have to use a separate thread. I also found example but those were in delphi not c++. Can I do this using `Intercept/IOHandler`, or I have to use separate thread ? Please give a short example code.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use `OnReceive` and `OnSend` event of Indy server and client to make it work in non-blocking mode.

Indy uses blocking sockets exclusively.  You cannot use them in a non-blocking mode.  There are no `OnReceive` and `OnSend` events, like there are in the VCL's `TClientSocket` and `TServerSocket` components.

> I have read that Indy server/client works in blocking mode, and to make it work i have to use a separate thread.

That is true.

Indy servers are multi-threaded.  `TIdTCPServer` has `OnConnect`, `OnDisconnect`, and `OnExecute` events that are triggered in the context of worker threads, one for each connected client.  `TIdUDPServer` has an `OnUDPRead` event that is triggered in the context of worker threads, one foor each listening port. You need to do your socket I/O in these events.  Typically, you would simply perform whatever read/write operations you need and let Indy block the calling thread as needed.

Indy clients are mostly single-threaded, they run in the context of whatever thread they are used in (`TIdCmdTCPServer` and `TIdTelnet` being the exception to that rule).  So you usually have to create your own thread to manage the socket I/O if you want non-blocking behavior.

Please read the [documentation](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/index.aspx) for more details:

[Introduction to Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/IntroIndy.html)

> I also found example but those were in delphi not c++.

And?  The components are the same in both languages.  So either translate the code from Pascal to C++, or just use the code as-is (did you know that you can use Delphi code in C++Builder projects? You can).

> Can I do this using Intercept/IOHandler

No.  An Intercept is meant for manipulating data as it passes to/from the connection (to apply encryption, compression, etc).  The IOHandler performs the actual I/O operations, but it has nothing to do with threading.

> or I have to use separate thread ?

Yes.

> Please give a short example code.

There are plenty of examples readily available if you search around.  StackOverflow is not the place to ask for them.

Comment: Actually when I write `idserver1->Intercept->` it shows me that `OnReceive` and `OnSend` events in it's context menu, thats why I thought that it might be possible to use these events with indy components. Thanx, I appreciate your help Sir.

Comment: Halo Sir, I have read the documentation, I think either its poorly documented or I am not good enough to understand. I just look for an **async chatting program example in c++**, for my school project. I found several example but none of them showing any way to detect the received data and send data without interrupting each other or anything else. At least if you can give me a link to such example, I'll be very great full to you sir.

Comment: Indy is not asynchronous. You are supposed to read data in a thread and let it block until the requested data arrives. On the client side you have to create your own thread. On the server side you can use a thread created by Indy. You can do reading and sending in separate threads so they don't block back other, or you can do them in the same thread if you use timeouts on reads so you give yourself opportunities for sends. I have provided dozens of examples on Borland/Embarcadero forums, AtoZed forums, StackOverflow, etc demonstrating how to use Indy asynchronously.